# swift / how set global variable in if statement

Tags: swift, global-variables

I have the following code and it's working.

```
if passedValue == "location1" {
        var initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 48.8618, longitude: 2.1539)
        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
        loadInitialData()
        }
if passedValue == "location2" {
        var initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 52.2398, longitude: 3.3579)
        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
        loadInitialData()
        }
```

But to be more concise, i write this , but i ve got the following error message : "Use of unresolved identifier 'initial location'". Any idea ?

```
if passedValue == "location1" {
        var initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 48.8618, longitude: 2.1539)
        }
if passedValue == "location2" {
        var initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 52.2398, longitude: 3.3579)
        }

centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
        loadInitialData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `var initialLocation: CLLocation!` outside and use `initialLocation` inside.

You probably also want to check if `initialLocation` is nil before using `centerMapOnLocation()` just in case.

```
if initialLocation != nil {
    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
}
```

Explanation: `centerMapOnLocation()` can't see `initialLocation` because it only exists inside of the `if` statements.

Full code:

```
var initialLocation: CLLocation!
if passedValue == "location1" {
    initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 48.8618, longitude: 2.1539)
}
else if passedValue == "location2" {
    initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 52.2398, longitude: 3.3579)
}

if initialLocation != nil {
    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
    loadInitialData()
}
```

Comment: there's no error message anymore, but when i'm launching, it's crasking and message is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. As if var initialLocation was nil...

Comment: ok, but how could i do that , so ? If initialLocation only exists inside of the if statement ? I have to keep my first code ? no way to be more concise ?

Comment: I added a complete solution. The problem with the first set of code is that you're repeating code. This way requires an extra check, but does not repeat any code.

Comment: Thx for your help ! i just have let "var" in if statement. After delete them , it's finally working. Thanks again